# css background-height makes element overflow

Tags: html, css, sass, compass-sass

I have a [webpage](http://stogrebro.com/page-test/) in which I want to set height of head to 60px, but somehow its inner elements overflow and thus it doesn't show right. I'm suspecting that the logo's background is somehow setting the height to be bigger than it should be. I'm specifically setting `background-size: 202px 56px;` and `height:56px;`. The original height of background image is 250x69px and it should be resized to (auto calculated)x56px (or fixed 202x56px would be ok too).

If this would be displaying right, there should be a small 'border' on the bottom which turns blue when its corresponding top element is hovered.

The styles are originally written in `SCSS` with help of [`Compass`](http://compass-style.org/) and compiled to `CSS`. I've also used `Compass` to generate sprites. I've only provided `CSS` files on webpage. I'm not putting any code here because it's too large (200+ lines in each file). If I have to show `SCSS` files, please let me know.

The webpage I'm editing can be found on this address: http://stogrebro.com/page-test/

*I'm originally creating this webpage on localhost so there might be some broken links. If there is anything important missing, please let me know.*

Comment: The page displays fine on Firefox and IE9 (with the grey border that turns blue on hovering), it only fails on Chrome. So maybe there's something webkit-specific you need to address, e.g. a -webkit- property somewhere you forgot? By the way, stupid question, but why are you creating a 250x69 graphic, and then resizing it to 56 high? I'm not sure about the design philosophy behind that.

Comment: The logo is old and this is the smallest that was designed. I do not have access to .psd files and when just resizing the png, the text turns pixely and I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i made some tries with your page and found out that the "over-height" of your `<td>` elements is due to the padding for anchor elements inside `<td>`. You have first to put it to 0 and then to apply the other paddings for left and right you are using:

```
#head table td a{ padding: 0px; }
```

Moreover you can just set the height directly to the `<div id="head">` and set it with hidden overflow (which also makes the trick but lets `<td>` with wrong height).

```
#head{ height: 60px; overflow: hidden}
```

The background-size works fine and doesn't make any mistake.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Oh, what a stupid mistake -.- I have completely missed that attribute. I've just removed the padding I was setting and it works like it should! you've possibly saved me hours of banging my head into the wall!